# Why is this list not aligning itself when is displayed in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer

It is aligned in Chrome and Firefox but in IE7 it looks like this:

http://ada.kiexpro.com/html/list.html

(I already fixed the z-index issue I just want to align the list vertically.)

Answer (score 0):

The changes that you have to make are as follows:

1. `div#leftmanulist`: make `padding:55px 0 0`
2. `div#abouttop`: make `position:absolute`
3. `div#aboutlist`: make `top:0px`

I think it should solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. The tr and th tags are causing the problem.